# Xcode 4.5 Single view app viewDidLoad not called on launch

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I'm new to iOS Development, so I using this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/) and this [tutorial](http://jleeiii.blogspot.com/2012/01/uistoryboard-power-drill.html) I began a project with a TableView embedded in a NavigationController.  But I've run into a couple problems, namely viewDidLoad isn't hit on launch in the simulator.  I've taken the sample project that goes along with the tutorial and ran it and the breakpoint in viewDidLoad is hit. 
  Here's the real kicker I create a simple single view app (out of the box, unchanged), and the break point is hit when I run iPad 6.0 Simulator, but not iPhone 6.0 Simulator!  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Answers to comments:** In all cases I've not manually instantiated the navigation controller in my AppDelegate and my view controller class is bound to my view via the storyboard.

Comment: check your Appdelegate Class whether you have added that `NavigationController` as `RootViewcontroller` or Added as `Suview`.

Comment: Did you link your class with the view controller in the storyboard? ("Identiti Inspector" -> "Custom Class")

Comment: Case is important.  `ViewDidLoad` != `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I've updated my original question to answer your questions and correct my caps.  Thank you all for your input thus far.